# Is it OK to have many graphs, tables, and images in a masters thesis?

Tags: thesis, masters, graphics, tables

I am writing my master thesis. In my document I have lots of tables. images and graph. Is this have a bad effect on any academic person when want to evaluate my  thesis.

I ask this question because I am afraid that they see my 
document say "look at his thesis , he fills all his document just by picture" . But I am really take time and effort to draw them and I absolutely think they are essential. So what is your idea ?

Comment: Any answer you might get here is infinitely less informed and thus less helpful than advice from your advisor, his or her postdocs and senior Ph.D. students, and faculty at your department who can take a look at your thesis and are familiar with the norm and culture in your field and subfield relevant to your thesis topic; we don't know what your thesis is about or your field, and have no idea what your thesis actually looks like...

Comment: @PouyanRafieiFard If you like to answer this question, please use "Your Answer" button. Please **do not** use **edit** to enter your answer.

Comment: **How much is too much?** May be a thesis has lots of experimental data or simulation output; and the researcher has to present all the graphs and tables. On the other hand, in a literature, psychology or sociology thesis, there may be two or three graphs or tables. Even, in some engineering or science thesis, there may be no graphs or tables and in another there may be lots of graphs. I think that answers to your question hugely depends on the major of the student who is writing his thesis or report and type of research which is done. Nobody can give you precise answer. Just ask your advisor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, it is perfectly fine if you want to put so many original pictures in your thesis and if you are writing a thesis in natural science, you can even put some pictures from other papers/books in your introduction chapter. Just try to imagine you are a thesis reader (a professor) with so many other things to do. They would like to read less text and see more comprehensive figures. Of course, making a figure comprehensive depends on the quality of your graphics as well as your caption text.

So here's what I suggest: anytime you want to put a figure in your text, ask yourself: how this figure is going to help my readers understand the main point? Is it conveying the main message? And how the captions will help to understand this message?

Remember, other people also have limited time and sometimes limited interest in what you did or even the task of evaluating the thesis, so it is up to you to make your material concisely so that they can understand about your intentions easily.